# ui-router bootstrap modal deep-linking?

Tags: angular-ui-router, bootstrap-modal, deep-linking

`parentA.bootStrapModal` and `parentB.bootStrapModal` are loading the same `modalController`.  the `modalController` gets data from my `modalFactory`.  So basically **all my child states are identical**.  Yuck!

Here's what I have today:

```
$stateProvider.state(
    'parentA',
    {
        url: '/parentA',
        template: '<p>Parent A <ui-view /></p>',
        controller: ['modalFactory', function(modalFactory) {
            ...do stuff and store in factory
        }]
    }
).state(
    'parentA.bootStrapModal',
    {
        url: '/bootStrapModal',
        template: '<span>Child A modal</span>',
        controller: 'ModalController' <------- Duplicate route
    }
).state(
    'parentB',
    {
        url: '/parentB',
        template: '<span>Parent B</span>',
        controller: ['modalFactory', function(modalFactory) {
            ...do stuff and store in parent B factory
        }]
    }
).state(
    'parentB.bootStrapModal',
    {
        url: '/bootStrapModal',
        template: '<span>Child B Modal</span>',
        controller: 'ModalController' <------- Duplicate route
    }
);
```

How can I have just **one** bootStrapModal that my app navigates to while also remembering the previous state scroll-bar position, boxes that were checked, and other UI elements?  Thanks for help!  Basically I want to persist everything in the previous route I can click the back button and everything still there.

Comment: http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/example/stickymodal/index.html#/